# How to create a hashmap in a controller in java and spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

I I have a controller which handles get and post requests. However in this class I want an instance of a `HashMap<int, Greeting>` which stores all my object of type Greeting. I only want it to be initiated once when GreetingController is called. Then I want to be able to store more and more greetings as more Greetings are created. How do I do that?

I will show you the code for both the controller (GreetingController) and my Greeting class.

Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {



    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        return "result";
    }
}
```

Here is the Greeting class:

```
package main.java.hello;

public class Greeting {

    private long id;
    private String content;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it as a static field ?

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    private static final Map<String, Greeting> hashMap =  new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Greeting>();

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetingForm(Model model,  @RequestParam(value = "greetingId", required = false) Integer greetingId) {
        Greeting greeting = hashMap.get(greetingId)
                return greeting.getGreeting();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        hashMap.put("1", greeting);
        return "result";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Controller
```

Is singleton by default, just add,

```
Map<String, Greeting> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Greeting>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a init method which will be called post constructor call

```
private HashMap<int, Greeting> myGreetings= null;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
   myGreetings= new HashMap<>();
   // Do more stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    private static final Map<int,Greeting> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetingForm(Model model,  @RequestParam(value = "greetingId", required = false) Integer greetingId) {
        Greeting greeting = hashMap.get(greetingId)
                return greeting.getGreeting();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        int count = hashMap.size();
        hashMap.put((count+1),greeting);
        return "result";
    }
}
```